# Minimum support for elevated buildings

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have been building elevated bases a little and believe that I have been going a little overboard with adding wooden pillars onto my elevated buildings in case the building is destroyed.

I was wondering if anyone knows how the supports work and what would be the maximum amount of objects that can be attached to one pillar at a time.

Comment: To go with Enigma's answer:  One thing that would help is that you can create the support near the ground/sea floor.  With Ark, if the structure is connected to each other, it doesn't matter if the pillars are connected to ceilings near the ground or up in the air.  I tend to make a "floor" of ceilings near the ground with pillars acting as additional foundation roughly every second ceiling.  Then use 1 pillar to go up in the air, then create the elevated structure.  It's easier to see a picture or video, but i don't have any sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if one support was necessary for one ceiling piece, that ceiling piece will also be destroyed along with anything vertically reliant upon it for support.

If you had a contingent pillar near enough to also support that ceiling piece, then it would not break.

Minimum support may not be what you are really asking about as minimum is enforced by what you can actually build or not.

One pillar can support 1-2 out from center in all directions. Corners will be cut on the second level out.

**To have a full, yet non-redundant contingency of pillars, you would probably want to build one every other space or under every 2nd piece out.**